# linear differential equation with ivp

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

Solve the differential equation:

$$x'(t) = \begin{bmatrix}a&1&0\\0&a&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}x(t)$$ with $x(t)=(x_1(t),x_2(t),x_3(t))$ and $a\in \mathbb R$.

Now I calculated the general solution $\phi(t)=c_1 e^{at}\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}+c_2 e^{at}\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}+c_3 e^{at}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$.

And there is a follow-up task: Calculate the solution with $x(0)=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Something is not correct as the eigenvalues should be $$a, a, 0$$ In fact, it is easy to find $z$ by inspection.

Comment: Also, the eigenvectors are likely not correct.

Comment: I made a stupid mistake in the question, the differential equation should be:

$x'(t) = \begin{bmatrix}a&1&0\\0&a&1\\0&0&a\end{bmatrix}x(t)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $t=0$, you have

$$\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\c_1\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}0\\c_2\\0\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}c_3\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}c_3\\c_2\\c_1\end{bmatrix}$$

which means $c_1=1$ and $c_2=c_3=0$.

Comment: As I mentioned above, I made a mistake is the question. The differential equation should be

$x'(t) = \begin{bmatrix}a&1&0\\0&a&1\\0&0&a\end{bmatrix}x(t)$